# sqlite c++ program values get inserted only first time second time they don't

Tags: c++, sqlite

when i try to insert values everything works fine for the first time but second time it doesn't take values,what should i do.?
after creating table i try to insert values which works fine,now second time again if i try to insert it doesn't take values
also when i want to select it is only displaying 1st column that is user id but i want the whole column to be displayed

```
        #include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>    
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string> 
 using namespace std;
#include "sqlite3.h"
 int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
int ch;
int userid;
string name;
 string sName;
int rc;
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_open("custom1.db", & db);
string createQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items3 (uid INTEGER primary key ,name TEXT);";
std::stringstream insertQuery;
std::stringstream selectQuery;
std::stringstream removeQuery;
while(ch!=5){
cout<<endl<<"1:create table"<<endl<<"2:insert data"<<endl<<"3:select data"<<endl<<"4:remove"<<endl<<"5:exit"<<endl;
cout<<"enter choice"<<endl;

cin>>ch;
switch(ch) {
case 1 :
  sqlite3_stmt *createStmt;
  cout << "Creating Table Statement" << endl;
  sqlite3_prepare(db, createQuery.c_str(), createQuery.size(), &createStmt, NULL);
  cout << "Stepping Table Statement" << endl;
  if (sqlite3_step(createStmt) != SQLITE_DONE) cout << "Didn't Create Table!" << endl;
break;


case 2 :
  sqlite3_stmt *insertStmt;

  cout << "Creating Insert Statement" << endl;
cout<<"userid:";cin>>userid;cout<<"name:";cin>>name;
insertQuery << "INSERT INTO items3 (uid,name)"
               " VALUES (" << userid << ", '" << name<<"')";
  sqlite3_prepare(db, insertQuery.str().c_str(), insertQuery.str().size(), &insertStmt, NULL);
  cout << "Stepping Insert Statement" << endl;
if (sqlite3_step(insertStmt) != SQLITE_DONE) cout << "Didn't Insert Item!" << endl;
sqlite3_reset(insertStmt);
sqlite3_close(db);
break;
case 3:
  sqlite3_stmt *selectStmt;

     cout << "Creating select Statement" << endl;
cout<<"userid:";
cin>>userid;
selectQuery<<"select * from items3 where uid="<<userid;
    rc= sqlite3_prepare(db, selectQuery.str().c_str(), selectQuery.str().size(), &selectStmt, NULL);
     cout << "Stepping select Statement" << endl;
while (sqlite3_step(selectStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    sName = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(selectStmt, 0);
   // Obj.Display(sName); //<== this is not display
    cout << "userid" << sName << endl;

  }
sqlite3_step(selectStmt);
     if (sqlite3_step(selectStmt) != SQLITE_DONE) cout << "Didn't Select Item!" << endl;
      else
     cout << "Success!" << endl;
sqlite3_close(db);
break;
case 4 :sqlite3_stmt *removeStmt;
cout<<"creating remove statement"<<endl;
cout<<"userid:";
cin>>userid;
removeQuery<<"delete from items3 where uid="<<userid;
sqlite3_prepare(db,removeQuery.str().c_str(),removeQuery.str().size(),&removeStmt,NULL);
cout<<"stepping remove statement"<<endl;
if(sqlite3_step(removeStmt)!=SQLITE_DONE)
cout<<"didn't remove item!"<<endl;
else
cout<<"success"<<endl;
sqlite3_close(db);
break;
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code? What is supposed to happen? What troubleshooting have you done so far? And please indent all your code!

Comment: If you want to get good marks and/or avoid getting fired, you should research *SQL injection*.

Answer (score 1):

Because you close the database connection after each insert.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ...
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_open("custom1.db", & db);
    ...
    while(ch!=5)
    {
        ...
        switch(ch) {
        ...
        case 2:
           sqlite3_stmt *insertStmt;
           ...
           if (sqlite3_step(insertStmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
               cout << "Didn't Insert Item!" << endl;
           sqlite3_reset(insertStmt);
           sqlite3_close(db); // <-- ERROR HERE
           break;
```

You open the database connection once at the program start, so you you should close the database connection once at the program end.

And to echo what Emil said, for God's sake indent your code properly! You might have spotted this yourself if your code wasn't such a mess.

Comment: i removed that statement
sqlite3_close(db) but still problem exists.

Comment: OK, but you should close the database connection at the end of the program. So just removing it is not the right thing to do.

Comment: i did that nothing happening

Comment: OK, then you should check the error codes returned from `sqlite3_step()` and `sqlite3_reset()` to give a clue as to what is going wrong.